# Got NoClassDefFound when running jcraft sshexec from Grails controller

Tags: grails, ant, jsch

I've got groovy class which is calling AntBuilder.sshexec method to execute remote command. This is working fine when I'm running this Groovy class as Java application. But, when I'm trying to call this class/method from controller, I've got error "Could not create type sshexec due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jsch/UserInfo".

Groovy class:

```
package filemanager

import com.jcraft.jsch.*
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.*

class FileWork {
    String servName
    String servUser
    String servPassword
    String servFolder
    String localFolder
    int    servPort
    String fileName

    FileWork (String p_servName, String p_servUser, String p_servPassword, String p_servFolder, String p_localFolder, int p_servPort,String p_fileName) {
        println 'Exec constructor'
        this.servName = p_servName
        this.servUser = p_servUser
        this.servPassword = p_servPassword
        this.servFolder = p_servFolder
        this.localFolder = p_localFolder
        this.servPort = p_servPort
        this.fileName = p_fileName
    }
    .....
     String runRemoteCommand () {//(Session p_ses) {
         try {
         def result = ''
         def ant = new AntBuilder()
         ant.sshexec(
           host: servName,
           port: servPort,
           trust: true,
           username: servUser,
           password: servPassword,
           command: "unzip -o ${servFolder}${fileName} -d ${servFolder}",
           outputproperty: 'result',
           verbose: false
         )
         return result
         } catch (Exception e) {
         println 'This is filemanager.FileWork.runRemoteCommandException'
        e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
package filemanager

import com.jcraft.jsch.*
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.*

class ChooseToController {

    def index(params)         {
       params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        //render params
        //model:[destServ: DestServ, fileName:fileName]
     }

    def copyToRemote(params) {
        def destServ = DestServ.get(params.id)
        //FileWork fileWork = new FileWork (destServ.getDestServName(), destServ.getDestServUser(), destServ.getDestServPassword(), destServ.getDestServFolder(), "C:/tmp/", destServ.getDestServPort(), params.fileName)
        //Session ses = fileWork.connect()
        //fileWork.copyToRemoteServ(ses)
        //ses.disconnect()
        FileWork fileWork3 = new FileWork ("###########", "test", "Test123", "/home/test/IN/", "C:/tmp/", 22, "1.zip")
        String result = fileWork3.runRemoteCommand()
        println(result)
    }
}
```

Dependencies:

```
runtime "com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.51"
runtime "org.apache.ant:ant-jsch:1.8.1"
```

Error:

```
Could not create type sshexec due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jsch/UserInfo
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntTypeDefinition.createAndSet(AntTypeDefinition.java:278)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntTypeDefinition.icreate(AntTypeDefinition.java:219)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntTypeDefinition.create(AntTypeDefinition.java:206)fro.....
```

Seems that not all classes are visible from grails runtime context...

Comment: The core Ant jar is build-scoped and only used to start up for `run-app`, `test-app`, etc. but isn't included in the War, and if you're using the default config in BuildConfig.groovy you're forking a second JVM to run the app with a smaller classpath that doesn't include the build jars. I would think though that having `ant-jsch` in runtime scope would work because that depends on `org.apache.ant:ant`. Does it work if you explicitly depend on that: `runtime "org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.1"` ?

Comment: Added dependency "org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.1", but still got the same error...